# How did I get a mortarboard badge on meta?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, badges, daily-reputation-badges

I just got the mortarboard badge

## yay

But I got it here, on meta, where I **cannot** earn rep.

How did that happen?

[image]

Comment: Fancy. I never knew that.